# Undefined offset: 0 in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, gammu

I just have that code in my model, and as a result of that, I got Undefined offset: 0
what should I do to solve that? I've tried declare new variable, but still nothing change.
Thank you

```
public function sendSMS() {
    $model2 = SibuStudent::find()->innerJoin('Sibu_Payment', 'Sibu_Payment.virtual_id=Sibu_Student.virtual_id' )->where('Sibu_Student.phone1 != "NULL" '  ) ->all();
    $model3 = SibuStudent::find()->innerJoin('Sibu_Payment', 'Sibu_Payment.virtual_id=Sibu_Student.virtual_id' )->where('Sibu_Student.student_name != "NULL" '  ) ->all();
    $model4 = SibuPayment::find()->where('Sibu_Payment.total_payment != "NULL" '  )->all();
    $model5 = SibuPayment::find()->where('Sibu_Payment.sms_status != "NULL" ')->all();
    $count = sizeof($model2);

    for($a=0; $a<5; $a++){
        if ($model5[$a]->sms_status == 0) {

        $no = $model2[$a]->phone1;
        $message = 'Kepada Bapak/Ibu dari '.$model3[$a]["student_name"].',tagihan (SPP,Asrama,Kantin,Adm) Rp.'.$model4[$a]["total_payment"].' dibayarkan sesuai tagihan. SMS ini tidak untuk dibalas, jika ada yang kurang jelas diberitahukan kepada siswa dan menanyakan kepada kami. Salam';

        if (strlen($message) < 160)
        {
            $outbox = new Outbox;
            $outbox->CreatorID = 'Gammu';
            $outbox->TextDecoded = $message;
            $outbox->DestinationNumber = $no;
            $outbox->save();
        }
    //batas for
    }
}
```

Comment: *Undefined offset* means that there is no element in your array with key `0`. Try to `var_dump` your `$model` variables, looks like at least one of them empty

Comment: Also as I see you compare against `"NULL"` which is a string, rather then `NULL`, so your where clauses should be e.g. `Sibu_Payment.sms_status IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try this way to find data from MODELs for `NOT NULL` clause. Do it for all your model that checks not null condition. Because your model has no element with key `0` in this case that why it returns `Undefined offset 0`

```
SibuPayment::find()->where(['not', ['Sibu_Payment.total_payment' => null]])->all();
```

> For example ['not', ['attribute' => null]] will result in the
>   condition NOT (attribute IS NULL)

Check More: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail

Comment: @Erjan Sarwono Sirait , glad it works for you, best of luck.By the way you can accept the answer.

Comment: after change to that code, i still have some error: Undefined offset: 0 again, i don't know what to change -_-
$model4 = SibuPayment::find()->where(['not',['Sibu_Payment.total_payment' => null]])->all();
$model5 = SibuPayment::find()->where(['not',['Sibu_Payment.sms_status' => null]])->all();